# How to format a sentence that a character has written down?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, italics

I'm trying my hand at editing a friends work. They've written the following:

> 'Thinks he's the smartest one in the room,' Henry wrote on a piece of paper.

(For context, they use double quotation marks when they write dialogue.)

My instinct is that the single quotation marks are incorrect. I could be wrong.

I can think of two alternatives:

1. Double quotation marks:

   > "Thinks he’s the smartest one in the room," Henry wrote on a piece of paper.

   I feel like the double quotation marks make it read too much like dialogue, however. Especially because there is a conversation happening around this line.
2. Italics:

   > *Thinks he's the smartest one in the room*, Henry wrote on a piece of paper.

   A reason I lean towards this option is because "thinks he's the smartest one in the room" is a thought that Henry is having. (If Henry was simply thinking the phrase then I would use italics.)

So, am I supposed use single quotes, double quotes, or italics in this situation? Or something else? Or is it just a matter of style?

Comment: If it's not scientific you might find answers in the WritersSE

Comment: @Helmar thank you--I didn't know WritersSE existed! I might try over there, then.

Answer (score 1):

**Marshal Plan** has a great book named "The Marshall Plan for Novel Writing",
Wherein he has recommended the use of ***ITALICS*** for the inner thoughts
In inverted comas- referred to by you as double quotes. :
http://www.dailywritingtips.com/dealing-with-a-characters-internal-thoughts/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm confident in using italics for inner thoughts. I didn't know whether this example fell under that umbrella, though, because in the sentence the phrase "thinks he's the smartest one in the room" is acting as a quote rather than a thought. So, are you saying that even though it's a quote, it's also still a thought and therefore the italics are used?

Comment: Yes true, a thought is analogous to talking to one self as if in mirror like a soliloquy. See Shakespearean plays where such instances abound.